# Uncaught TypeError: document.title is not a function, line 31

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to write a notification script with javascript but I get the following error when executing the `js`:

> Uncaught TypeError: document.title is not a function

Here's my script:

```
function notif() {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    $.ajax({
        type:"get",
        url:"cgi-bin/check",
        success:function(data) {
            var title;
            if (data) {
                if (data.indexOf("disconnected.ogg")>-1) {
                    if (data.indexOf("SSH")>-1) {
                        title = "SSH Disconnected";
                    }
                    else if (data.indexOf("VPN")>-1) {
                        title = "VPN Disconnected";
                    }
                    else if (data.indexOf("IP")>-1) {
                        title = "IP Not Found";
                    }
                    var audio = new Audio("disconnected.ogg");
                    audio.play();
                }
                else if (data.indexOf("connected.ogg")>-1) {
                    title = "Angel Beats!";
                    var audio = new Audio("connected.ogg");
                    audio.play();
                }
                $.ajax({
                    url:"cgi-bin/remove"
                });
            }
            document.title(title);
        }
    });
    setTimeout(notif, 1000);
}
notif();
```

How can I fix it ?

Comment: Use `document.title = title`

Comment: thanks it's fixed now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is correct; `title` isn't a function of the `document`, it's a property.

```
document.title = title;
```